# Simulate / emulate pressing keyboard button or mouse button in jquery

Tags: jquery

is it possible to simulate/emulate pressing keyboard button or mouse button in jquery? I'm sure that it is possible, but how to handle it?

Comment: Look at this: **[stackoverflow - Simulate Keypress With jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468384/simulate-keypress-with-jquery)**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821071/jquery-script-for-simulated-key-press-down-not-running-keyboard-shortcut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
$('a').trigger('click'); // Mouse click 
$(document).trigger('keydown'); // Keyboard
```

But you will need to add the events in order to be able to trigger them:

```
$('a').on('click',function() { // do something });
$('document').on('keydown',function() { // do something });
```

Answer (score 0):

> From official dos:
>
> .trigger() Description: Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to
>   the matched elements for the given event type.
>
> Any event handlers attached with .on() or one of its shortcut methods
>   are triggered when the corresponding event occurs. They can be fired
>   manually, however, with the .trigger() method. A call to .trigger()
>   executes the handlers in the same order they would be if the event
>   were triggered naturally by the user:

```
$('#foo').on('click', function() {
      alert($(this).text());
    });
    $('#foo').trigger('click');
```

'click' can be replaced with an event from [Keyboard Events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/) or [Mouse Events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/) .