# Automatically run Keyboard shortcut on HTML page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyboard-shortcuts

I need to run a keyboard shortcut on my HTML page before the page get completely loaded. How do i do this by using Jquery or Javascript.

I need to run this code mentioned below,

> Refresh a webpage (no cache) -> Ctrl + F5

Comment: While this is highly unlikely to be a possibility (just consider how easy it would be for a spammer/hacker to abuse), you might like to explain what problem you are trying to fix with this as there's likely to be a more suitable solution.

Comment: some images on my site are not loading correctly....but when i use **Ctrl + F5** it loads correctly. is there anything else to rectify this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get what you are trying to do here but triggering keyboard events can't be done as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35245783/7797002).

You could however refresh the page using:

```
location.reload();
```

And there are different events that you could use for example:

```
window.onload = function () { location.reload(); }
```

But this seems like an odd thing to do, could you provide more information about what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: I tried this method but it didn't work..need to **Reload without Cache**

Comment: some images on my site are not loading correctly....but when i use Ctrl + F5 it loads correctly. is there anything else to rectify this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should try to avoid the issue instead of looking for a way to "cheat" and reload the images. Have you tried adding a timestamp to the name of your image to fix the caching issue?