# Simulate keyboard press in javascript

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome

I would like to ask, if there is a possibility to simulate more keypresses at once using javascript.
My problem is, that I have a window which is blocked to be closed, but for administration purposes I need to close it sometimes using some kind of hack, unfortunately chrome disables javascript to close current tab if it wasn't created by javascript.
So one thing came to my mind and it is to simulate pressing CTRL+W in javascript which will close current tab and I will be able to leave chrome.
I am using --kiosk to keep user without any other options to close the window.
So my idea was to have an input which in case that I will put e.g. 123 inside it will simulate the action of keyboard.
Is this even possible, or do any of you guys have any better solution?

Thanks in advance!
Jakub

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13821309/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery script for simulated key press down not running keyboard shortcut](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821071/jquery-script-for-simulated-key-press-down-not-running-keyboard-shortcut)